# Installing bunsenlabs linux from live usb to hard disk

Tags: linux, crunchbang

No OS is installed on my system. So I am trying to install bunsenlabs linux from BIOS through live usb, but when I click on install option I get an error saying CD is not inserted in CD-ROM.
I want to install the linux in hard disk but not in CD, please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you make the bootable usb by linux, use "dd" command.
If using windows, you should make the bootable usb by using rufus, and then choose DD method.

Answer (score 0):

First enter into terminal which is available in installation step then make directory cdrom if it doesn't exist. Then mount the USB on that folder and then unplug the USB for few seconds and then check again.